# Mapping component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

i use .map to mapping components but i have to using key prop top don't have an error on my console, so i did this :

```
 <Container key={props.number.toString()}>
  <CardTop>
    <Avatar></Avatar>
    <ContainerInfos>
      <Name>{props.name}</Name>
      <Stars>{fields}</Stars>
    </ContainerInfos>
  </CardTop>
  <CardBottom>
    <p>{props.paragraph}</p>
  </CardBottom>
</Container>
```

and my mapping here :

```
  {Avis.map((item, i) => (
      <Card
        key={i}
        number={i}
        name={item.nom}
        paragraph={item.texte.slice(0, 200)}
        avis={item.note}
      ></Card>
    ))}
```

the problem is : even with a key prop, the error on console is here.

but when i remove the component in loop and I put a simple div with prop : key={i} it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I suspect if you add `key` to the direct children to `<Card>` it would work, however, just use a [Keyed Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#keyed-fragments).

```
 {
  Avis.map((item, i) => (
    <React.Fragment key={i}>
      <Card
        number={i}
        name={item.nom}
        paragraph={item.texte.slice(0, 200)}
        avis={item.note}
      ></Card>
    </React.Fragment>
  ));
}
```

Fragments are just containers that don't get rendered as any HTML and are perfect for scenarios like this.

Comment: No.. same error : " index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Comment: Could you update your Q with `index.js` - I’ve tested the above code and it works without an error so it sounds like it’s coming from elsewhere. Have you got any other `.map`?

Comment: Oh i found ! it was because on my Card component i had to add key prop on other item...